# Wait/Notify dead lock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, wait

I have a queue with some blocking mechanism in "Add" and "Get" methods, where first thread adds data and second thread gets  data.

```
public synchronized MyObj getData() {               
    synchronized (myLock) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (isEmpty()) {                
                wait(0);                    
            }
        }       


        return getData();           
    }
}

public synchronized void addData(MyObj data) {
    if (!isFull()) {
        putData(data);
        synchronized (this) {
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, if first thread tries to get data and queue is empty i put in wait  via wait(0) until other thread add data to queue an release from waiting via notify().

Now I want to add another "lock" when queue is full and some one tries to add more data to it:

```
public synchronized MyObj getData() {               
    synchronized (myLock) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (isEmpty()) {                
                wait(0);                    
            }
        }       

        synchronized (this) {
            notify();
        }
        return getData();           
    }
}

public synchronized void addData(MyObj data) {
    synchronized (myLock) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (isFull()) {
                wait(0);
            }
        }
    }

    synchronized (this) {
        notify();
        }
        PutData(data);
}
```

The result is not what I expect , I guess that i get a dead lock cause process is stuck.

**UPDATE**

This is how I get data:

```
queueSize--;
startPointer = (startPointer + 1) % mqueueSize;
data = (String) queue[startPointer];
```

this is how i add data

```
  queueSize++;
  endPointer = (endPointer + 1) % mqueueSize;
  queue[endPointer] = data;

public synchronized boolean isEmpty() {
        return queueSize== 0;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isFull() {
        return queueSize== mqueueSize;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have three `synchronized` statements? The `wait(0)` only releases the lock on `this`, so just keep that one and dump the `synchronized` from the method and the `synchronized(myLock)`.

Whenever you call wait on some object (in this case you are calling on `this`), the lock on that object is automatically released to allow the other thread to proceed. But you are never calling wait on `myLock` (and nor should you, because you are calling on `this` already). That part is redundant and causes the deadlock.

Consider this scenario: the thread that is supposed to add takes the lock on `myLock` but finds the queue full, so it waits. This wait does not release the lock on `myLock`. The other thread wants to take data but cannot enter the `synchronized` block because the first thread did not release the lock on `myLock`.

Conclusion: remove the `synchronized(myLock)` blocks.

Comment: what about synchronized (this)  on the notify, i still need it right?

Comment: @kenny, yes otherwise it will throw an IllegalMonitorStateException. Calls to wait and notify must be inside a synchronized block on the same object.

Comment: now the flow works fine until I need to exit (no more data), in my logic I just add null to the queue but some how it's stuck at the end.

Comment: strange, but it doesn't happen all the time..., after testing it i've found out that if it's stuck, it stuck in get method.

Comment: @kenny, maybe you should move the notify after the point where you actually put something. Same for the get.

Comment: may this cause a problem: the thread that adds data to queue has more then one reference to the queue object (same object that exists in hashmap, just different references)

Comment: I've added synchronized to methods and everything worked! why?

Comment: @kenny because now your entire code is sequential since only one thread can enter the lock. So practically there is no deadlock because there is no parallelism. :)

Comment: i don't get this, one thread can't add data and other can't read data at the same time? my queue is an array with 2 pointers (head and tail) that i alter accordingly to the method called, ofcourse pointers can't be modified by 2 threads in the same time.

Comment: @kenny: if you put synchronized on both methods then they cannot be simultaneously called by two threads.

Comment: wait, i have 2 threads. first one only adds data to queue and the second thread only gets data from queue (no thread does 2 operations, just one). I need both of the threads to work in parallel will this work with synchronized methods?

Comment: @kenny: If you have several methods with synchronized in the same object, it's equivalent to putting the entire code of each method inside synchronized(this). So all threads entering any one of the methods needs to acquire the lock on this. Hence, two threads accessing even different methods cannot execute them in parallel.

Comment: so, how should I fix the problem I am having? I've added more code to my post to show how do I add and read data to queue. maybe there is problem with isfull and isempty, because they also synchronized?  What about the fact that I must prevent prevent  2 threads alter pointers in the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't take a look in [java.util.BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). Probably it will be useful in your situation.

Particularly take a look at [java.util.LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#LinkedBlockingQueue%28int%29), where if you specify the queue's capacity in the constructor, then the queue will block.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `synchronized` keyword from your method signatures, as that implies you hold the `this` monitor for the whole method call -- the `synchronized(this)` blocks are simply redundant.

EDIT:

...Then call wait and notify on `myLock` rather than `this`. And forget completely about synchronizing on `this`. This is because while waiting (on `this` in your current code), you're not releasing the `myLock` lock, so the other thread is not able to get to `notify()`.

Comment: other answer tells me to remove synchronized(myLock) and you are telling me to remove synchronized(this)... I am confused...

Comment: remove one of them :). It's enough to use one, that's the key point. And it's also kind of mandatory in your case for getting rid of the deadlock.

Comment: I will not debate here on which one is better to remove, but I'll just state that I would rather not keep the synchronization on `this`, but on some private monitor object instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if` with `while`. It won't hurt to double check, if the collection really become not empty/not full.

You don't really need two locks. Single lock will work almost as well and should be much simpler.

```
public synchronized T get()
{
    while(isEmpty())
        wait(0);

    notifyAll();

    return super.get();

}

public synchronized put(T t)
{

    while(isFull())
        wait(0);

    super.put(t);

    notifyAll();

}
```

All threads will wake up when something changes. But if they can't do their work, they will `wait` for next `notify`.

Comment: why single lock is enough? if thread will try to add data to a full queue,in a loop, it will hit   "if (!isFull())" constantly.

Comment: @kenny It might not be necessary, but in general case there can be several threads waiting.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, your code has too many `synchronized` annotations. Also, the condition to `wait` on is checked in an `if` conditional, but it should ideally be checked in a `while` loop to avoid [*spurious wakeups*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29). Here is the outline of the code that fixes these.

```
// _isEmpty and _getData are private unsynchronized methods
public MyData get() throws InterruptedException {
  // wait and notify should be called from a block
  // synchronized on the same lock object (here myLock)       
  synchronized (myLock) {
    // the condition should be tested in a while loop
    // to avoid issues with spurious wakeups
    while (_isEmpty()) {
      // releases the lock and wait for a notify to be called
      myLock.wait();
    }
    // when control reaches here, we know for sure that
    // the queue is not empty
    MyData data = _getData();
    // try to wake up all waiting threads - maybe some thread
    // is waiting for the queue not to be full
    myLock.notifyAll();
  }
}

// _isFull and _putData are private unsynchronized methods
public void put(MyData obj) throws InterruptedException {
  synchronized (myLock) {
    while (_isFull()) {
      myLock.wait();
    }
    _putData(obj);
    myLock.notifyAll();
  }
}
```